# C++ Windows link subsystem question

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, subsystem

When using the windows SDK to compile a program writen in C++, if I specify `-subsystem:windows,6.1`,
the width of the window is smaller. If I don't, or do `-subsystem:windows` without the `6.1`, the width is normal.

I'm curious why this does this, and if there's a way to make it stay the same width regardless of what command line I pass to link.

**EDIT:** So it's also height, height and width are both different. And if i look at it with Inspect.exe, it says the size is the same each time.

**EDIT2:** Also it's a window application created with CreateWindow, not a console.

**EDIT3:** Here's the full code that initializes my window:

```
wcex.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(SMALL_ICON));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
wcex.lpszClassName  = g_szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(SMALL_ICON));

g_hMainWnd = CreateWindow(
    g_szWindowClass,
    t_szWindowTitle,
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    392, 250,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);
```

And I resize the window with this:

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL,
    (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN)/2)- (392/2),
    (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN)/2) - (250/2),
    392, 120, SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Comment: Whoa, wait, what? The Windows SDK has a C++ compiler?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yeah? cl.exe and link.exe.

Comment: I thought that was part of Visual C++ and also part of the WDK, not a part of the SDK... what folder is it in?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe

If you open `Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt` and you have the windows sdk installed, you should have them all available.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that part of Visual Studio?

Comment: Mmmm nope, I only have the windows SDK installed, and I have the compilers/linkers/tools.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew the SDK installer made a Visual Studio folder... good to know.

Comment: I would guess that with the subsystem version specification, your console window gets a TrueType font.

Comment: Oh I guess I should have specified, its a window application with WinMain.

Comment: @Josh: sorry, my "make sense of it" circuit translated your subsystem spec to a spec saying console. Are  you talking about *default* size of window?

Comment: Windows can behave differently depending on what you set these values to; unfortunately I can't find any official documentation on what this would affect.  Probably it is mostly for preserving backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm suspecting you are specifying some windows styles that are only supported in Windows7 (Win7 = 6.1).  Post the full CreateWindow call with arguments and also try turning off Aero.  The window border may be included in the width/height for example in one scenario.